# NodeJS Lambda + API Gateway timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following lambda: (NodeJS18). The purpose is to use puppeteer to open a browser and generate a report, save it as PDF, upload it to S3, get a presigned URL as a response. It works fine until a point, because if I use the `console.log(presignedUrl)` I can see the actual url, the only issue is that my lambda times out.

It does not seem to be a resource problem (I think) because from the 1024MB of RAM allocated it only seems to use ~700MB. Also, after 2-3 timeouts, every successive call is ok and it works. If then I wait for a few more minutes and try again, I'll get a few timeouts and then it starts working again.

I read in some posts that it might be due to the fact that the lambda tries to restart, or I am not closing some connections properly, but nothing seems to work so far.

Highly appreciate any answer!

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdf-lib").PDFDocument;
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const FRONTEND_URL = process.env.FRONTEND_URL;
const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.SLEEP_STUDIES_BUCKET;

const lambdaError = (error) => {
  return {
    errorType: "InternalServerError",
    httpStatus: error.statusCode,
    code: error.statusCode,
    statusCode: error.statusCode,
    message: error.message,
    error,
  };
};

async function processReport(studyId, scoreSetId, sectionsList, onSpot = false) {
  const sections = [
    "main",
    ...sectionsList.split(","),
  ];
  console.info("open browser");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
    headless: "new",
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    args: [...chromium.args, "--hide-scrollbars", "--disable-web-security"],
  });
  try {
    const isSecondPageVisible = [
      "oxygenSaturationTRT",
      "arousalTRT",
      "snoreInTst",
      "cardiacTST",
      "movementEvents",
      "positionStatistics",
    ].some(key => sections.includes(key));
    let trendsPageNumber;
    if (isSecondPageVisible && sections.includes("note")) {
      trendsPageNumber = 4;
    } else if (!isSecondPageVisible && !sections.includes("note")) {
      trendsPageNumber = 2;
    } else {
      trendsPageNumber = 3;
    }

    let totalPages = 1;
    if (isSecondPageVisible) {
      totalPages++;
    }

    if (sections.includes("note")) {
      totalPages++;
    }

    if (sections.includes("trends")) {
      totalPages++;
    }

    let range = `1-${totalPages}`;
    if (sections.includes("trends")) {
      range = `1-${totalPages - 1}`;
    }

    console.info("generate report");
    let report = await generatePdf(
      browser,
      studyId,
      scoreSetId,
      sections.filter(section => section !== "trends"),
      range,
      onSpot,
      false,
      totalPages,
    );
    if (sections.includes("trends")) {
      const landscapePage = await generatePdf(
        browser,
        studyId,
        scoreSetId,
        "trends",
        "1",
        onSpot,
        true,
        totalPages,
        trendsPageNumber,
      );
      console.info("merge reports");
      report = await mergePdfs(report, landscapePage);
    }
    console.info("save report");
    const fileUrl = await savePdf(studyId, scoreSetId, report, onSpot);
    console.info("close browser");
    browser.close();
    console.info("browser closed, returning response for filename", fileUrl);
    return {
      message: "Report generated and uploaded to S3!",
      fileUrl,
    };
  } catch (e) {
    console.info(e);
    browser.close();
    console.info("browser closed, returning error");
    e.statusCode = e.statusCode ?? 500;
    throw e;
  }
}

async function generatePdf(
  browser,
  studyId,
  scoreSetId,
  sections,
  range,
  watermark,
  landscape,
  totalPages = 4,
  trendsPageNumber = 4,
) {
  try {
    console.info("open new page for ", sections.toString());
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let url = `${FRONTEND_URL}/report/${studyId}/${scoreSetId}/print?sections=${sections}&totalPages=${totalPages}&trendsPageNumber=${trendsPageNumber}`;
    if (watermark) {
      url += `&watermark=${watermark}`;
    }
    console.info("navigate to page", url);
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
    await page.addStyleTag({
      content: `
      @page {
        size: A4 ${landscape ? "landscape" : "portrait"} !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
      }
      .navbar {
        display: none;
      }
      `,
    });
    await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
    console.info("generate report for pages ", range);
    return await page.pdf({
      margin: "none",
      footerTemplate: "",
      printBackground: true,
      format: "A4",
      landscape,
      pageRanges: range,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
}

async function mergePdfs(portraitPages, landscapePage) {
  try {
    const pdfsToMerge = [portraitPages, landscapePage];
    const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();
    for (const pdfBytes of pdfsToMerge) {
      const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
      const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
      copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
        mergedPdf.addPage(page);
      });
    }

    return await mergedPdf.save();
  } catch (e) {
    console.info(e);
    throw e;
  }
}

async function savePdf(studyId, scoreSetId, buffer, onSpot = false) {
  const path = `${studyId}/reports/${scoreSetId}/${onSpot ? "draft-" : ""}report-${new Date().getTime() / 1000}.pdf`;
  const client = new S3Client({});
  const command = new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: path,
    Body: buffer,
  });
  await client.send(command);
  console.log("file uploaded on s3", path);

  if (!onSpot) {
    return path;
  }

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: path,
  };
  return await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("getObject", params);
}

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  if (!FRONTEND_URL) {
    const error = new Error();
    error.message = "Frontend URL not found!";
    error.statusCode = 500;
    throw error;
  }

  if (!BUCKET_NAME) {
    const error = new Error();
    error.message = "Required S3 Environment Variables aren't found!";
    error.statusCode = 500;
    throw error;
  }

  // @Todo: extract authorization token and pass it as query param in FE
  const { sections, onSpot, sleep_study_id, score_set_id } = event;
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  processReport(sleep_study_id, score_set_id, sections ?? "", onSpot)
    .then((response) => {
      callback(null, response);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      e.statusCode = e.statusCode ?? 500;
      callback(lambdaError(e));
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come in and ask themselves the same question:

In a scenario where you have lambdas linked with API Gateway, it does not matter what timeout the lambda has, but rather the 29s (maximum) timeout that API Gateway has. So your lambda (including the cold start) should give a response back to API Gateway in a maximum of 29s, otherwise API Gateway will simply send a timeout response.

The way we solved this issues was by creating another lambda that invokes this one asynchronously and gives back an answer to API Gateway in the required amount of time.

Comment: Do you have the example code for this?